# The Caverns of Primitive Polynomial GF[2]

Tags: polynomials, graph-theory, recreational-mathematics, finite-fields

With [primitive polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimitivePolynomial.html), it's not too hard to get all the polynomials of a particular power.  For example, columns in the following represent the 18, 16, 48, and 60 primitive polynomials of GF[2^7], GF[2^8], GF[2^9], and GF[2^10]:

[image: cavern 7]

[image: The Primitive Cavern]

[image: Cavern 9]

[image: Cavern 10]

You can also enter at the left, visit every white space, and exit at the right.  It's a continuous connected cavern.

But here, I got lost in the caverns of GF[2^12]. I wasn't able to visit all the white spaces, and likely got eaten by a grue.  Is there an optimal way to shuffle this set of primitive polynomial coefficients?

[image: Eaten by a grue]

Here's more bad, dangerous caverns for all the primitive polynomials in caverns for powers 5 to 14.

[image: dangerous caverns]

Can the orderings of these primitive polynomials be made as safe as the solution for GF[2^7]-GF[2^10] at the top? Here are best found so for for GF[2^11] and GF[2^12]

[image: Cavern 11]

[image: Cavern 12]

Comment: Is the rotational symmetry in the three good patterns an accident?

Comment: Symmetry helps to simplify the problem.

Comment: @EthanBolker: My guess would be that the rotational symmetry comes from the fact that the reciprocal of a primitive polynomial is always also primitive. The ordering of the columns may be such that the reciprocals appear at opposite ends.

Comment: @EdPegg How do you computationally generate all the primitive polynomials for a given power ? Your caverns are very beautiful.

Comment: Module[{prime = 2, pow = 12, div},
 div = Reverse[Divisors[prime^pow - 1]];
 Select[Total[
     MapIndexed[
      x^(#2[[1]] - 1) #1 &, #]] & /@ (Reverse[Flatten[{1, #}]] & /@ 
     Tuples[Range[0, prime - 1], {pow}]), 
  IrreduciblePolynomialQ[#, Modulus -> prime] &&
    Length[
      Union[Table[
        PolynomialMod[x^div[[k]], #, Modulus -> prime], {k, 1, 
         Length[div]}]]] == Length[div] &]]   -----

This code will generate the primitive polynomials for GF[2^12].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A large bounty by Archmage Gruber prompted me to take another excursion into the caverns of the Galois Fields.  It's said that some young fellow met his death in a duel amongst these grounds. Despite the obvious dangers, I delved in with new equipment.  I wasn't able to improve GF[2^11] and GF[2^12] all that much, but at least I escaped unscathed at the other side. I should likely try giving up on symmetry, but it's hard to do that while traveling in a group.

[image: GF 11]

[image: GF 12]

I also ventured into GF[2^13] and GF[2^14].  It's difficult just to get to the other side with these caverns, but I spent a few days trying to make them safer. But I doubt that making them completely safe is possible.

[image: GF 13]

[image: GF 14]

Not the bounty of success that I had hoped for.  But an interesting excursion, nevertheless.

UPDATE:  GF[2^11] perfectly solved. Here are two solutions.

[image: Galois Field 2^11] 
[image: Galois Field 2^11]

UPDATE 2:  GF[2^12] almost perfectly solved.

[image: Galois Field 2^12]